# How can pickled byte data be unpickled?

Tags: python, pickle

How can pickled data be written and read back from a BytesIO object?

I tried:

```
import io
import cPickle as pickle

s1 = "foo"
bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
pickle.dump(s1, bytes_io, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
s2 = pickle.load(bytes_io)
```

which gives for the pickle.load line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just did not rewind your buffer: [`bytes_io.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) before `pickle.load`.

Possibly you don't want to rewind to the front of the buffer, but just to the start of your pickled data. Then read out the stream position with [`bytes_io.tell()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.tell) before pickling and seek to that position instead of `0`.